# Latitude/Longitude regexp issue

Tags: regex, validation

I want to use regular expression for matching string representing latitude and longitude, in following form:

```
N2°55'12.33''E31°22'43''
N02°55'12.33''E31°22'43''
S2°55'12.33''E31°22'43''
```

But for now I want to focus on the first part, that checks only the latitude. I want to match those strings:

```
N2°55'12.33''
N02°55'12.33''
N42°55'12.33''
```

Where the first number goes from 0 to 90, the second between 0 and 59, and the third between 0 and 59.99. I'm using the following regex:

```
^(N|n|s|S)(\d|[1-8]\d|90)°(\d|[1-5]\d)'(\d|[1-5]\d)(\.(\d|[1-9]\d))?''
```

I've following problems:

- The regex matches `N2°55'12.33''` but not `N02°55'12.33''`. I cannot handle the leading zero after `N`.
- If the first number is `90`, other values must be `0`. This because maximum value of latitude must be `N90°00'00''`, and I cannot have `N90°01'00''` for example.

It should not be a big deal for me to limit the maximum value of latitude to `N89°59'59.99''`, so if the second point it's too complicated I can handle it, but I need the optional leading zero in the number range for all three numbers.

The main problem that I've is that I cannot have an arbitrary number of leading zeros, o I cannot use something like `0*` in the expression, and the leading zero must be used only if I've only a digit. So those are valid:

```
N02°55'12.33''
N2°55'12.33''
N22°55'12.33''
```

But those strings are not valid:

```
N002°55'12.33'' (more than one leading zero)
N052°55'12.33'' (a leading zero in a two-digits number)
```

How can I handle the leading zero in the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be over-simplyfying a bit, but in order to include an optional leading 0 you could change your range to `[0-8]`. 90° should be handled as a completely separated use case:

```
^(N|n|s|S)((\d|[0-8]\d)°(\d|[0-5]\d)'(\d|[0-5]\d)(\.(\d|[0-9]\d))?|90°00'00)''
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PIeOBi/1)

Answer (score 1):

Would this help:

```
^[nNsS](?:0?[1-9]|[1-8]\d|90(?![^']+[1-9]))°[1-5]?\d'[1-5]?\d(?:\.\d?\d)?''$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mwKWHQ/1)

---

- `^[nNsS]` - Start-line anchor with one of given character;
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group to allow for alternation;

  - `0?[1-9]` - An optional leading zero in front of digit 1-9;
  - `[1-8]\d` - A 1-8 followed by any digit;
  - `90(?![^']+[1-9])` - Literally '90' but negative lookahead to prevent any digit 1-9 later on;
- `°[1-5]?\d'[1-5]?\d(?:\.\d?\d)?` - Digits between given delimiters and an optional decimal point with given digits;
- `''$` - Closing double apostrophe and end-line anchor.

**Note:** You can remove the question mark in the optional decimal group to only allow for two trailing decimals.

Comment: Thanks a lor for the expression.

Answer (score 1):

I made some modification to your regex:

```
old:
^(N|n|s|S)(\d|[1-8]\d|90)°(\d|[1-5]\d)'(\d|[1-5]\d)(\.(\d|[1-9]\d))?''
new:
^(?:N|n|s|S)(?:(\d|[0-8]\d)°(\d|[0-5]\d)'(\d|[0-5]\d(?:\.(?:\d|[0-9]\d))?)''|90°00'00(?:\.\d{1,2})?'')
Explanation:
^
 (?:N|n|s|S)                               - Change to non-capturing group
 (?:                                       - Add non-capturing group 
   (\d|[0-8]\d)°                           - Change 1 to 0
   (\d|[0-5]\d)'                           - Change 1 to 0
   (\d|[0-5]\d(?:\.(?:\d|[0-9]\d))?)''     - Change 1 to 0
   |                                       - OR
   90°00'00(?:\.\d{1,2})?''                - Add special case for 90° with optional decimals
 )
```

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/HTmEBR/1)

I changed many of your groups to non-capturing ones to only capture the numbers and keep your output less-noisy. You can see it pretty well on regex101 on the right side. If you actually need to capture everything, you can remove the corresponding `?:`.

Main changes were using `0` instead of `1` and adding an extra case for `90°`

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should do the trick:

```
[NS](90°0?0'0?0(\.0+)?|[0-8]?\d°[0-5]?\d'[0-5]?\d(\.\d+)?)''
```

You'll notice that I've removed the lowercase variants and use `[NS]`. You can combine this with the case insensitive flag `i` to also match lowercase variants. If you don't have the ability to adjust the regex flags, you can use `[NnSs]` instead.

We then start of with the regex `90°0?0'0?0(\.0+)?` which matches `90°00'00`. It also matches variants with a decimal point and minutes/seconds represented with a single digit. `90°0'0`, `90°0'0.0`, `90°00'0.00`, etc. are all matched.

Then we'll use `[0-8]?\d°[0-5]?\d'[0-5]?\d(\.\d+)` as the alternative. Like you can see it is structured similarly as the former, but instead of `0` it uses `\d` (aka `[0-9]`) for the second digit. The first digit is optional and limit to `0-8` for degrees and `0-5` for minutes and seconds. This regex allows `02°55'12.33`, `2°55'12.33`, `02°05'12.33`, `02°5'12.330`, etc.

[image: regex diagram]

<sup>[Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%5BNS%5D%2890%C2%B00%3F0%270%3F0%28%5C.0%2B%29%3F%7C%5B0-8%5D%3F%5Cd%C2%B0%5B0-5%5D%3F%5Cd%27%5B0-5%5D%3F%5Cd%28%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%3F%29%27%27)</sup>

Currently there is an unlimited amount of decimals allowed. You can replace the `+` quantifier with `{1,n}` to limit to `n` decimals (replace `n` with a number).

I've removed the `^` anchor, since it's not relevant for the question. You can add it back if you need it.

Also note that the groups used are capture groups `(`…`)`. You can replace these with non-capture groups `(?:`…`)` if you want. I personally like the shorter notation.